# Does Python requests session keep page active?

Tags: python, python-2.7, session, request, phantomjs

So I am currently writing a script that will allow me to wait on a website that has queue page before I can access contents

Essentially queue page is where they let people in randomly. In order to increase my chance of getting in faster , I am writing multi thread script and have each thread wait in line.

First thing that came to my mind is would session.get() works in this case?

If I send session get request every 10 seconds, would I stay hold my position in queue? Or would I end up at the end?

Some info about website, they randomly let people in. I am not sure if refreshing page reset your chance or not. But best thing would be to leave page open and let it do it things.

I could use phantomjs but I would rather not have over 100 headless browser open slowing down my program and computer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep sending the session, as long as you keep the Python application running you should be good.

Comment: So if I send a get requests, would session keep it active?(almost as if I open a url on browser and left it open until I close browser, which will close connection). Not that I don't believe you, but I just want to test it out for my education purpose, do you know of any example or website I could use to test out this?